# Getting the child element of a particular div element using beautiful soup

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape table data from this link

http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?date=30-01-2017&venue=ST&raceno=2&lang=en

Here is my code

```
from lxml import html
import webbrowser
import re
import xlwt
import requests
import bs4

content = requests.get("http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?date=30-01-2017&venue=ST&raceno=1&lang=en").text # Get page content
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml') # Parse page content 

table = soup.find('div', {'id': 'detailWPTable'}) # Locate that table tag

rows = table.find_all('tr') # Find all row tags in that table

for row in rows:
    columns = row.find_all('td') # Find all data tags in each column
    print ('\n')
    for column in columns:
        print (column.text.strip(),end=' ') # Output data in each column
```

It is not giving any output . Please help !

Answer (score 0):

[image]

The table is generated by JavaScrip and `requests` will only return html code like the picture shows.

Use `selemium`

Comment: Whis this is correct, I don't know why you have included the picture, eh?

Comment: But when I print the data using print(table ) , it returns the div element which means we have reached this div table . Now we have to just get the table child of this div element . How can we do this ?

Comment: @Ardour Technologies  disable the JS in your browser and view the page source, that will returned by `requests`.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to mention that id you are using are for the wrapping div, not for the child table element.

Maybe you could try something like:

```
wrapper = soup.find('div', {'id': 'detailWPTable'})
table_body = wrapper.table.tbody
rows = table_body.find_all('tr')
```

But thinking about it, the tr elements are also descendants of the wrapping div, so find_all should still find them %]

Update: adding tbody

Update: sorry I'm not allowed to comment yet :). Are you sure you have the correct document. Have you checked the whole soup that the tags are actually there?

And I guess all those lines could be written as:

```
rows = soup.find('div', {'id': 'detailWPTable'}).find('tbody').find_all('tr')
```

Update: Yeah the wrapper div is empty. So it seems that you don't get whats being generated by javascript like the other guy said. Maybe you should try Selenium as he suggested? Possibly PhantomJS as well.

Comment: Yes , But can you please tell how to reach to this table element because it does not have any id of its own ?

Comment: Still not working . Giving this error rows = table_body.find_all('tr') # Find all row tags in that table
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'find_all'

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at the last line of your code:

```
print (column.text.strip(),end=' ') # Output data in each column
```

Are you sure that should read `column.text`. Maybe you could try `column.strings` or `column.get_text()`. Or `column.stripped_strings` even

Comment: No this is actually correct . I wrote this line for the other link of this website and it was giving the desired output . The problem here is that it is not giving any output along with the error I posted above .

Answer (score 0):

You can try it with [`dryscrape`](https://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/) like so:

```
import dryscrape
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import re
import xlwt

ses=dryscrape.Session()
ses.visit("http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?date=30-01-2017&venue=ST&raceno=1&lang=en")
soup = BS(ses.body(), 'lxml') # Parse page content 

table = soup.find('div', {'id': 'detailWPTable'}) # Locate that table tag

rows = table.find_all('tr') # Find all row tags in that table

for row in rows:
    columns = row.find_all('td') # Find all data tags in each column
    print ('\n')
    for column in columns:
        print (column.text.strip())
```