# Getting the HTML code after Javascript has been loaded

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape this website. I want to get the main table. But the problem is the table gets loaded through Javascript. So the HTML code of this table cannot be scraped. Here is the code.

```
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver 
import time

driver = webdriver.PhantomJS(executable_path='') 
driver.get("http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?date=30-01-2017&venue=ST&raceno=5&lang=en") 
time.sleep(3)
pageSource = driver.page_source
bsObj = BeautifulSoup(pageSource) 
print(bsObj.find(id="detailWPTable").get_text())
```

I want to get the contents of the table. Please help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41889513/getting-the-child-element-of-a-particular-div-element-using-beautiful-soup  you ask same question yesterday.

Comment: I did not get the solution yesterday . Where to get the answer then ?

Comment: refine your question and add comment in the answer, it will be active again, and community will see it.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with [`dryscrape`](https://dryscrape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) like so:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS
import dryscrape

ses=dryscrape.Session()
ses.visit("http://bet.hkjc.com/racing/pages/odds_wp.aspx?date=30-01-2017&venue=ST&raceno=1&lang=en")
soup = BS(ses.body(), 'lxml') # Parse page content 

print(soup.find(id="detailWPTable").get_text())
```

Output:

```
No.ColourHorseDrawWt.JockeyTrainerWinPlaceWin & Place1FURIOUS PEGASUS6132O MurphyT K Ng278.42HAPPY FIERY DRAGON5132N CallanD Cruz3.21.03HAPPY WAY WINNER12132K C NgK W Lui207.64EMPIRE OF MONGOLIA1128C Y HoC S Shum39105DYNAMIC VOYAGE4125K C LeungL Ho185.16OPTIMISM10124C SchofieldD E Ferraris124.37TREASURE AND GOLD13124J MoreiraC H Yip5.53.38MANHATTAN STRIKER3122O DoleuzeC Fownes124.39CHANS DELIGHT2121M ChadwickD Cruz176.510SHOW MISSION14121H W LaiY S Tsui278.311FRIENDS FOREVER7119K K ChiongK L Man9.73.512STARRY STARLIES11115H T MoP O'Sullivan146.013INTELLECTUAL GLIDE9113M L YeungA Lee146.114BERNARD'S CHOICE8113K TeetanT K Ng175.2F Field
```